# How to append values of a string variable in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have a String variable that receives the different values, I need to append the different values received in the same variable, I have used StringBuilder but I can't append, how can I do that?

```
private void receive(byte[] data) {
    String msg = new String(data);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(msg);
    Log.e("DEBUGRX-->", String.valueOf(sb));
}
```

Comment: Use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) like this way

```
private void receive(byte[] data) {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(data);
    msg.append(msg);
    Log.e("DEBUGRX-->", msg.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder Class.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Some String");
sb.append("Some String");
```

Like this, it is simple!